# Incorporating an Automatic Image Montage using JSON to pull from PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I found this automatic Image Montage that I am trying to use in my website however, the images have been hard coded into the HTML. I wanted to bring them in dynamically so that I can easily change out the images from a database.

Image Montage: http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/index8.html

I managed to get my images to come in using jQuery but, the CSS calculations for the image height and left gets added using JavaScript. Now that I am no longer hard coding the images directly into HTML, it seems as though these calculation are not occurring at all. Does anyone know how to fix this problem so that the images are dynamically being calculated after the images load.

My site: http://129.219.78.186/~masgis/puppychow/index8.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use PHP to load the images?

Just drop this in where the static images are in the example inside am-container:

```
<?php
$dir="/home/user/images";
$dir_handle = @opendir($dir) or die("Unable to open $path");
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 
{
    if($file!="." && $file!="..") {
        echo "<a href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/$file\"></img></a>\n";
    }
}
closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

This worked for me.